# Chrome Visibility: Collapse

Tags: css, google-chrome, visibility

I have a page with several tables on it. To improve readability the body of each table is collapsed, so the user just sees the header and the footer. There is a button to toggle it to expand.

In IE and Firefox, it works great. But in Chrome and Safari, there is white space in the place of the collapsed row. Is there a workaround for those two browsers that will remove the white space?

Here is example code:

```css
.collapse {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>This is a Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='collapse'>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL 1</td>
      <td>TOTAL 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: did you check the answer?

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: I thought I had. Sorry.

Comment: Sure :) no problem. A voteup will also be appreciated (once you have enough reputation ;) )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42252682/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome and Safari treat `visibility: collapse` as `visibility: hidden`.

This will only work in Firefox/IE.

You can change it to `display: none` to make sure it works the same in all browsers, however this way you will miss the general idea of the `collapse` value, where all the width/height of the table's elements are calculated and take into account while affecting other elements in the table:

```css
.collapse {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>This is a Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='collapse'>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL 1</td>
      <td>TOTAL 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```