# What's the difference between visibility: hidden and visibility: collapse in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, language-lawyer, specifications

In the [CSS flexible box layout module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#visibility-collapse), it says:

> the collapsed flex item is removed from rendering entirely, but leaves behind a "strut"

Does that behave just like `visibility: hidden`? If the answer is yes, then why was `visibility: collapse` introduced?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

***Note on browser support:*** As of July 2017, Chrome (59) does not support `visibility: collapse`. The code samples below with `collapse` work in Firefox and Edge, but fail in Chrome (they behave just like `hidden`). UPDATE: As of July 2020, this is note is still valid. Chrome and Safari treat `visibility: collapse` like `hidden`. [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=visibility%20collapse)

---

Flex items are laid out in a row or column, depending on `flex-direction`.

Each row / column is considered a [***flex line***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-lines).

In the examples below, a flex container has four flex items in row-direction. The fourth item wraps, creating a second flex line:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
</div>
```

---

### `display: none`

With `display: none`, a flex item isn't rendered by the browser.

If all items on the flex line have `display: none`, the line also collapses, which affects the rest of the layout. Surrounding elements may shift when a flex line collapses.

With `display: none` applied to the third item, the fourth item takes its place on the upper line, and the lower line collapses:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box3 { display: none; }
```

```html
<code>display: none</code>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
</div>
```

---

### `visibility: hidden`

With `visibility: hidden`, a flex item is rendered by the browser but is fully transparent. It's hidden from view but takes up the space it would normally use in the layout. Hence, surrounding elements see this item as fully intact.

In this example, when the last two boxes have `visibility: hidden`, the rest of the layout (including the second flex line) remains unchanged.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box3 { visibility: hidden; }
.box4 { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<code>visibility: hidden</code>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
</div>
```

---

### `visibility: collapse`

With `visibility: collapse`,  a flex item is not rendered (same as `display: none`), but the flex algorithm checks the cross size of the item and then uses that data to keep the flex line stable (i.e., what the cross size of the line would be if the flex item was `visible`).

The difference with `display: none` is that `collapse` allows one piece of the item – its cross size – to be preserved. This is referred to in the spec as the *strut*.

So if all flex items on the line have `visibility: collapse`, the cross size of the line (whether it be the width or height) *does not* collapse, and the rest of the layout isn't affected.

Note that although `collapse` guarantees the stability of the line's cross size, it provides no such assurance for the line's main size. This is a key difference between `collapse` and `hidden`.

Below are some examples. (As mentioned above, these won't work in Chrome. Test in FF or Edge.)

In this example, the first two items have `visibility: collapse`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box1, .box2 {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<code>visibility: collapse</code>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
</div>
```

The layout renders like `display: none`. The second line collapses because the main size of the items is gone, allowing the last item to move up naturally.

In the following example, all items get `visibility: collapse`. Hence, the second line collapses because the items' main size is gone, but the cross size of the first line remains.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<code>visibility: collapse</code>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh8mqLpn/)

Comment: In short: since visibility: hidden doesn't actually affect layout, no, they are not at all the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! The spec says webkit passes the test of collapsed items, so I thought chrome behaves right and didn't test with firefox and edge. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the element. If used on a table sub-element, `collapse` will hide the element as well as the space it occupied.

`collapse` will behave like `hidden` if used on any element that is not a table sub-element