# CSS: "visibility: collapse" still takes up space

Tags: html, css

I want to hide rows from a HTML table, and I do that with `visibility: collapse;`. Now I've realized that the table height shrinks when I do that (as it should!), but that the page height stays the same, leaving an empty space scrollable.

Consider this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                background-color: #a0a0a0;
            }
            td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                font-size: 120%;
            }
            tr.collapsed {
                visibility: collapse;
            }
            html {
                background-color: #c0c0c0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td></tr>
            <!-- Repeat this line 20 times -->
            <tr class="collapsed"><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td></tr>
            <!-- Repeat this line 20 times as well-->
        </table>
        <p>
            Hello!
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When showing that in Firefox or IE, the page always has the same height as if the rows weren't collapsed, even if the table itself is not larger and the text underneath it does not keep distance to it.

How can I prevent this from happening? When I "make the table smaller" by hiding rows, I hope that the surrounding page gets smaller as well...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility not really sure what to make of what it says about collapse. It's hidden but the table size is calculated as if it was not hidden so visually the space is there lol

Comment: I've interpreted it as *the dimensions of the not-hidden rows/cols are calculated like it was not hidden*.

Comment: But it says `the space they would have occupied is removed (as if display: none were applied to the column/row of the table)` anyway, I never had to use this and probably never will

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42252682/3597276

Answer (score 8):

The [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property, as the name implies, only makes elements invisible, they still take up space though.

If you want to hide a row in a table you could just set `display: none` on it.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 120%;
}
tr.collapsed {
  display: none
}
html {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td></tr>
  <!-- Repeat this line 20 times -->
  <tr class="collapsed"><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td><td>Test 1 2 3</td></tr>
  <!-- Repeat this line 20 times as well-->
</table>
<p>
  Hello!
</p>
```

Comment: W3Schools says (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp): "*collapse removes a row or column, but it does not affect the table layout. The space taken up by the row or column will be available for other content.*" If I use `display: none`, the layout will completely ignore the collapsed row, which is not what I want – the layout "jumps" when toggling the rows to be hidden/shown.

Comment: Maybe you could post a complete example of what you're trying to accomplish. It's not clear from the original question that the rows will be toggled on and off. What you're trying to achieve might not be possible with CSS alone.

Comment: I am just removing or adding the `collapsed` class from/to the rows with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of cheating, but it reduces the height and keeps the width of the cells in the row:

```
tr.collapsed {
    visibility: collapse;
    line-height: 0;
}
tr.collapsed * {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Some screenshots (depicting bottom of the table, the last cell is made wider to make the effect on the column width visible):

No change:

[image: No change]

`line-height` property added:

[image: line-height property added]

`padding` property added:

[image: padding property added]

`border` property added:

[image: border property added]

`visibility` property added:

[image: visibility property added]

As you can see, erm, as you have to believe me, the page has not any more height as the visible table, but the width of the collapsed cell still has effect. :-)

Comment: While it is cheating, something like this worked for me, because I needed the collapsed rows to participate in horizontal column layout. Since I was using constant height rows, I used height instead of line-height.

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the table element.

I can't recreate the exact problem you are having (I think it might be fixed in Firefox)
but adding overflow:hidden; does still affect the `.scrollHeight` of the containing element in Firefox, which has the effect of reserving lots of space and causing e.g. incorrect scrollbar sizes.

Comment: I've just tried it and it indeed seems to have the desired effect!

Answer (score 1):

in tr.collapsed try display: none; it worked for me ;P

Comment: Then the layout "jumps" when I toggle the class, because the row will be ignored when determining the column widths.

Comment: Maybe try in JS change background of that row on like that one in body or something

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with that! :D

Comment: Sorry for my English I'm still studying. Try in javascript change a color of background. Make it the same with background color of your table container. Row will disappear but still will be there.

Comment: But then the row will still take the space, which is what I want to get rid of by hiding it.